# подключение к БД SQLite в ListView при помощи метода

Tags: java, android, база-данных, listview, sqlite

написал подключение к БД с помощью метода connectDataBase()

```
public class EditGroup extends ListActivity
{
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListView listNameGroup = getListView();                   

        connectDataBase();

        cursor = db.query("groups", new String[]{"_id", "name_group"},null, null, null, null, null);

        CursorAdapter listNameGroupAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.activity_edit_groups, cursor, new String[]{"name_group"},
                new int[] {R.id.nameGroup},0 );

        setListAdapter(listNameGroupAdapter);

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }

    public void connectDataBase(){
        DataBaseCard db = new DataBaseCard(this);
        db.open();
    }
}
```

но при создании активности происходит ошибка, вроде как при создании курсора.., в чем может скрываться проблема?
вот кусок лога..

```
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.card.az.EditGroups.onCreate(EditGroups.java:50)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
```

код БД

public class DataBaseCard   {
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "azcard.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "groups";

```
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_GROUP = "name_group";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SUBGROUP = "subgroup";
private DataBaseCardOpenHelper dataBaseCardOpenHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DataBaseCard(Context context){

    dataBaseCardOpenHelper = new DataBaseCardOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

public void open(){
    db = dataBaseCardOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close(){
    if (db != null)
        db.close();
}

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SCRIPT = "create table " + TABLE_NAME
        + " (" + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_NAME_GROUP
        + " text not null unique, " + COLUMN_NAME_SUBGROUP + " text not null unique);";

public class DataBaseCardOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DataBaseCardOpenHelper(Context context, String DB_NAME,
                                    SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int DB_VERSION){
        super(context,DB_NAME, factory,DB_VERSION);

    }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SCRIPT);

   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
       db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
       onCreate(db);
   }
```

}

```
public void addGroup(String addNewGroup) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME_GROUP, addNewGroup);
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME_SUBGROUP, addNewGroup);
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Думаю не помешает и код класса БД

Comment: код класса БД добавил..

Comment: Вы случайно `setContentView()` не пропустили после `super.onCreate()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в методе `connectDataBase` вы инициализируете переменную, которая является локальной переменной метода и не имеет ничего общего с полем класса, хоть и называется так же. Поэтому в методе `onCreate` при попытке вызвать  `db.query` выскакивает `NPE`, т.к. `db == null`. Измените метод `connectDataBase` следующим образом, и данная ошибка должна пропасть.

```
public void connectDataBase(){
    db = new DataBaseCard(this);
    db.open();
}
```

UPD:
Т.к. поле класса имеет тип `SQLiteDatabase`, то класс `DataBaseCard` нужно изменить так, чтобы он смог возвращать объект `SQLiteDatabase` который создается в методе `open()`. Один из вариантов это добавить геттер, который будет возвращать этот объект:

```
public SQLiteDatabase getDatabase(){
    return db;
}
```

тогда метод `connectDataBase` должен выглядеть так:

```
public void connectDataBase(){
    DataBaseCard databaseCard = new DataBaseCard(this);
    databaseCard.open();
    db = databaseCard.getDatabase();
}
```

А вообще, не совсем понятна суть класса `DataBaseCard`. То, что он делает сейчас не дает никаких преимуществ, а только заставляет делать лишнюю работу.

Comment: Ваша мысль вроде понятна, но в таком случае начинает ругать на db = new DataDaseCard(this) .. мол объявляем переменную типа SQLiteDatabase , а присваеваем значение DataBaseCard.. ну и если же здесь навести порядок, и объявить вверху кода вместо

private SQLiteDatabase db;

вот так:

 private DataBaseAzCard db;

то начинает ругаться на метод  query курсора..

Comment: @ZigZag дополнил ответ

Comment: все равно из за разности типов данных не видит в этом случае метод getDatabase(); суть класса DataBaseCard в принципе взять на себя работу с БД (вставка, удаление записей и т.п.), в нем же и внутренний хелпер, помогающий создать БД..

Comment: @ZigZag я неправильно указал имя геттера в своем коде, сейчас исправил ```connectDataBase``` на ```getDatabase```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вместо `this` поставить `getApplicationContext();`

Comment: в данном случае контекст отрабатывает правильно